# Efficient way to access document by key in inside array of documents?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

In JavaScript, I need an efficient way to access a document in an array that has the following form:

```
[
    { 
      a : '1',
      b : '2',
      c : '3'
    },
    { 
      a : '4',
      b : '5',
      c : '6'
    },
    {...},
    {...}
]
```

So, all the documents have the same keys. If I have the value for `a` (for example `a = 4`), is there a way to retrieve the document where `a = 4` from the array without looping through all elements in the array and performing the check?

Comment: What do you mean by _documents_ ?

Comment: a document is an object in the array as I understood so far

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With just the data structure you show, there is no way to retrieve the object where the key `a` is === `'4'` without some code that loops through the array.  Arrays don't have have any powers to find content in nested objects within them without looping.

It would be possible to build a separate index of that array or to restructure the data into a different type of data structure that would then allow you to retrieve the desired item without looping, but not as you have the data structured there.

For example, you could loop over the array once and build an index of all the values of `a` present in the array such that with one access from that index, you could know which array elements contain the desired value of `a`.  But, you'd have to first build that type of index before you could use it.  If this was a one time access, that wouldn't save you any time, but if you were going to be looking up values of `a` over and over again, it could save a lot of time.  Build the index once, then use it many times to improve the efficiency of finding a specific value.

---

To make a more efficient way of finding data if the array is large, here's a scheme for indexing the data once and then using that index many times after that.  This assumes the data is a string or has a non-ambiguous string conversion (which your example fits):

```js
var data = [
    { a : '1', b : '2', c : '3', d : '1'},
    { a : '4', b : '5', c : '6', d : '1'},
    { e : '3', a : '1', c : '5'},
];

function ArrayIndex(data) {
    var index = {};
    data.forEach(function(obj, i) {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
            var combinedKeyVal = "_" + key + "_" + obj[key];
            var slot = index[combinedKeyVal];
            if (!slot) {
                slot = index[combinedKeyVal] = [];
            }
            // add this index to the slot array
            slot.push(i)
        });
    });
    
    this.find = function(key, val) {
        var combinedKeyVal = "_" + key + "_" + val;
        return index[combinedKeyVal] || [];
    }
}

var index = new ArrayIndex(data);
var found = index.find('a', '4');
log(found);
found = index.find('d', '1');
log(found);
found = index.find('c', '5');
log(found);
found = index.find('d', '2');
log(found);

// display output in snippet
function log(x) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(x);
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. At this stage it seems I will only be accessing the array once, so I think I'll just have to loop through, but if it turns out that I need to perform multiple accesses, I will definitely use this strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var document = arr.filter(function(element) {
    return element.a === '4';
}, arr)[0];

console.log(document);
```

Comment: This is still looping though all the elements in the array.  The OP asked for a method that is "without looping through all elements in the array".

Comment: I know that.. It could be a solution to not use loops explicitly. We don't know what exactly the op wants..

Comment: Yes, sorry, should have been more specific. I want to avoid looping altogether, for performance. However, it seems it will be unavoidable in this case. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should read about [binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). There are many JS implementations on the Internet.

Comment: A binary search can only be used if the data is properly sorted by the value that is being looked up.

Comment: I know that. I thought this algorithm would be helpful because in your code all `a` are arranged in ascending order.

Comment: Sorry, that is a bad example on my part. The data is in fact not arranged in any order, and the values '1, 2, 3, ...' can be strings as well. But thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to access objects in the array by the 'a' key, and it is possible to restructure your array as a JSON Object, you could do this:

```
var jsonObj = {
   '1': { b: '2', c: '3' },
   '4': { b: '5', c: '6'},
   ....
}
```

Then you can retrieve the object with the '1' key like this:

```
jsonObj['1']
```

(Note that numbers in JSON as keys aren't valid, so you wouldn't be able to use jsonObj.1)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm retrieving the array in that form from a database, so restructuring is not an option, but thank you.